# Azure WebSite AppSettings maximum sizes

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

What is the maximum size (string length) of an AppSetting Key and its Value? All I have found is the maximum permitted size of an ASP.NET Web.Config file which is 250 KB by design.

- Does this apply to "the total" of all Azure WebSite AppSetting
  configurations which I set in the Portal?
- And what are the permitted Key and Value (string) lengths in both web.config and portal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There does not appear to be a max key / value size.

[Max key/value length in 'application configuration' files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382758/max-key-value-length-in-application-configuration-files)

However, you are correct in the max file size for web.config by default being 250kb.

https://serverfault.com/questions/180963/increasing-web-config-size-limit